# Why are views not copied over when using SQL Server Log Shipping?

Tags: sql-server-2008, view

I have 2 Sql Servers (2008) with Log Shipping setup between them. The receiving server is configured to keep the database in Read-Only mode. When creating a view on the primary server, this view is not copied over to the secondary. It was my believe that any DDL statements are also shipped. Can anyone clarify?

Comment: Is the view in the log shipped database?

Comment: The view was added to the logshipped database some time after logshipping was started, so yes its in the logshipped db

Comment: What is the delay between shipping the logs over to the standby server, and did you happen check between this delay? Also, are the DML statements being applied to the standby?

Answer (score 3):

All modifications to the source database will be copied over to the target database, assuming that your log shipping process is not broken or blocked.  The target database must be in read-only made (which in your case it is) but users accessing the database will prevent SQL from applying the transaction log.

Log shipping needs to be able to put the target database into single-user mode before applying the logfile.  This is the one serious drawback of log-shipping.  Try disconnecting all users, then wait for log shipping to get caught up.  Your view will appear.